# Top command number of process limit for -p option

Tags: linux

Linux command top -p option can allow up to 20 processes. Is there any way that I can specify more than 20 process?

Something like 
top -pN1 -pN2 .... -pN30

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/), it has nice scrolling, colors and everything.

(although this question should be on SuperUser rather that stackoverflow)

Comment: in fact, i have to use the output of the top command on my perl scripts, so i cannot use htop to do this job

Answer (score 0):

Interactive programs are a bad source of input to scripts. I strongly advice you to consider ps(1) utility; it has a lot of different process selection options, can output arbitrary column set with fine-tuned field formatting, can do sorting.